# What would be a python alternative to a system like nanoc?

Tags: python, ruby, nanoc

Is there a python *publishing system* (have no idea whether this is an appropriate name for such a thing, but they're calling it that way) similar to [nanoc](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/)? Generally, a *thing*  which will convert a lot of markup/asciidoc files to HTML in an orderly fashion?

I know of python-markdown, but one by one page with no support for outside .css pages is not what I'm looking for?

So, is there something python based of more or less this *quality?*

Comment: Another discussion on ssgs: http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/jaqn2/pelican_vs_hyde_static_website_generators/

Comment: A possible appropriate name: static site generator.

Answer (score 5):

Some website are built using [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) which was for documentation purposes but could be extended to a static website easily. (e.g. http://redhotchilipython.com/)

Answer (score 5):

I know what nanoc is but I never use it, so I can't do comparison. These are some Python generators you can consider:

- [Blogofile](http://www.blogofile.com/): a static website compiler and blog engine (there is #blogofile irc channel on freenode)
- [Chisel](https://github.com/dz/chisel): a simple Python static blog generation utility (last update March 2009)
- [Hyde](https://github.com/hyde/hyde): static website generator powered by Python & Django (version 0.5, which is in development, lacks features if compared to 0.4 and is not well documented, but it should be easier to use).
- [Pelican](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican): a simple weblog generator (there is #pelican irc channel on freenode)
- [poole](https://bitbucket.org/obensonne/poole): an easy to use Markdown driven static website generator (I used it, does its job well)
- [PyGreen](http://pygreen.neoname.eu): a small framework based on Bottle and Mako to create web sites that can easily be exported as static web sites

From what I can say, at the moment static site generators in Ruby are more feature complete and mature, though you should be able to find a solution right for you in Python, too.

Answer (score 5):

I have compiled a [list of projects similar to nanoc](https://nanoc.ws/about/#similar-projects).

Comment: That link was pointing to this list of > 400 static site generators: https://staticsitegenerators.net/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this compares to nanoc:

- https://github.com/lakshmivyas/hyde, example: http://hgtip.com/

Comment: I saw hyde earlier, and kinda liked it ... but the docs for it are horror. Do you know of a tutorial or some "for dummies" docs for it?

Answer (score 1):

The closest equivalent seems to be [StrangeCase](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/StrangeCase). The author even mentions the similarity:

> I just read about nanoc, and realized that it is the Ruby equivalent to StrangeCase. I commend them! I had considered porting StrangeCase to Ruby (and maybe I will some day, just for kicks), but for now, I would say to Rubyists: use nanoc.